# Regex to parse HTML Color

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I'm trying to parse a HTML color components (#RRGGBB) using a regex, I'm trying this approach:

```
NSRegularExpression *re = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^#?([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})$"
                                                                    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                      error:&err];

NSArray *matches = [re matchesInString:hexColor
                               options:0
                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, hexColor.length)];
```

but I think that can be simplified, so this next only stores the last match:

```
NSRegularExpression *re = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^#?([0-9a-fA-F]{2})+$"
                                                                    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                      error:&err];

NSArray *matches = [re matchesInString:hexColor
                               options:0
                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, hexColor.length)];
```

so, what am I missing? how can the first approach be simplified? Thanks...

**Edit**

I had used the approach provided by @Arkanon:

```
NSRegularExpression *re = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^#?((?:[a-fA-F0-9]{3}){1,2})$"
                                                                        options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                          error:&err];

NSArray *matches = [re matchesInString:hexColor
                                   options:0
                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, hexColor.length)];
```

but I'm only matching one time, when I look for matches:

```
for(NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSRange redRange    = [match rangeAtIndex:1]; // first capture group (range is {1,6})
    NSRange greenRange    = [match rangeAtIndex:2]; // second capture group (throws an exception)
    NSRange blueRange    = [match rangeAtIndex:3]; // third capture group        
}
```

How can I get each component using a simple regex? Thanks.

Comment: Your regex is a little bit without sense..you provide the same regex [0-9a-fA-F]{2} for 3 times that is equivalent to write [0-9a-fA-F]{6}. But the best answer is the Arkanon one who is arrived before me to reply. Whit that regex you can also include the short code color.

Comment: I don't think you can simplify your regex *and* retain the grouping. If you've already validated that the input is 6 characters matching a hex string (via Arkanon's solution), then manually parsing the string is quick, albeit more verbose, but a fine solution imo.

Comment: @MatteoGobbi the nonsense regex @"^#?([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})$" works extracting each (RGB) component please look at my edit to be more explicit.

Comment: Do you really need to use a regular expression for this? There's a much simpler and direct way to parse a color string in the format `#RRGGBB` into the 3 color components.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, I know several other ways. I'm just trying to do the validation and parsing on one step using a regex. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to match the R, G and B components separately, then you must have three separate capture groups, so you can't get much more compact than your first regex. Add to this the fact that a CSS hexadecimal colour can be either three or six hex digits in length, and you will end up with an even more complex regex pattern if you need to match all valid CSS hex colour values.

Comment: This matches a hex color, but doesn't parse it into color components by grouping.

Comment: Thanks, please look at my edit, indeed the comment by @Jimmie is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Replaced the answer now that the question has been clarified.

Comment: Thanks, Is not extracted from a CSS exactly, is the result from a web service (that's the reason for the optional '#'). I will take your answer as valid.